# Управление несколькими VPS

Tags: сервер, vps

В организации работаю со множеством клиентов, провожу для них доработки, настройки и т.п.
Для каждого клиента покупаю VPS и туда заливаю код, настраиваю окружение и конфиги для работы.
Как-то можно держать контроль над множеством серверов? Что-то вроде единой панели, в которой будут все VPS, возможность управлять ими?
В данный момент вход в аккаунт и все управление происходит на каждый VPS индивидуально, каждый раз выхожу с панели и логинюсь на другой аккаунт.
В будущем может быть 10, 20, 50 и т.д. VPS.
Сейчас все VPS держу на debian.

Comment: Ну в том же ispmanager в бизнес панели разве нет этого? Именно бизнес версия, не обычная.

Comment: хм, надо будет проверить.
я также думал, что-то наподобие одной панели для входа через ssh